# How can I cast or initialize ImageInputStream with InputStream?

Tags: java, image, inputstream

I am developing an image scraping application. I am getting URL

```
URL imageUrl = new URL(imageSource);
```

Then I'm creating an InputStream with this URL:

```
InputStream is = new URL(imageUrl.toString()).openStream();
```

After this I wanna create an ImageInputStream to determine ImageIO readers.

```
ImageInputStream iis = ??????
```

But I couldn't initialize this. Can I implement URL or InputStream for ImageInputStream?

Comment: Did you try `iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this is what you are looking for :

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
URL imageUrl = new URL(imageSource);
InputStream is = new URL(imageUrl.toString()).openStream();
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(is);
Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);

if(!iter.hasNext())
    throw new RuntimeException("No readers found");
ImageReader reader = iter.next();
```

This is how you get your reader, or one of the ways of getting the reader. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use `ImageIO.read(url)` that returns `BufferedReader`

Comment: @ssimm IMHO it is better relatively to methods suggested by OP. It is really the same as method suggested by Harmeet Singh 1 minute after me.

Comment: It may cause OOM issues for very large image files on limited JVM heap size. Consider reading bufferdimage of for example, 60000x30000